# How to determine important variables in decision tree

Tags: regression, classification, cart

I have created decision tree model on Auto dataset.

tree.auto = tree(highmpg ~ .,df)

I have attached the plot and copying the summary.

```
> summary(tree.auto)

Classification tree:
tree(formula = highmpg ~ ., data = df)
Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] "horsepower"   "year"         "origin"       "weight"       "displacement"
Number of terminal nodes:  13 
Residual mean deviance:  0.2311 = 87.59 / 379 
Misclassification error rate: 0.05867 = 23 / 392
```

Now, I am wondering how to find the most important variables impacting highmpg. Should I do it from the split in the tree plot?

Please advise.[image: tree plot]

Comment: The ones that are used for splitting first are the ones that are most important w.r.t. optimizing the split criterion. As pointed out by @Emma Jean, however, usually its better to use Forrests instead of a single tree

Answer (score 1):

You could perform pruning on your tree which essentially removes branches that do not make a significant impact on your error rate. Your other option is to use your same data to build a random forest model. From a random forest model, you should then be able to obtain values of "variable importance".

You may want to take a look at *An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R*. It has a chapter titled "Tree Based Methods" which I think would be very applicable to you. If I am not mistaken, there should be a free version of this textbook floating around on the web.